# Aligning lists into a desirable order

Tags: java, list

I currently have two working lists:

```
for(String s:l ){
  System.out.println("1 x " +s );
}

for(double f:c){
  System.out.println("total cost");
  System.out.println("£"                +f);
}
```

This could potentially be a really stupid question, that's not possible since it's a list.
But as it stands it prints out:

```
1x thick
1x bacon
1x ham
total cost £8.75
total cost £2.5
total cost £1.0
```

Is there any possibility that I could get it so it is displayed as:

```
1x thick      total cost £8.75
1x bacon      total cost £2.5
1x ham    total cost £1.0
```

Comment: The thread hasn't formatted how i put it

Comment: basically instead of a new line for each list, one can go besides the other one so in a sense it's still a list but it just looks better and clearer

Comment: I formatted your actual/expected output, but I'm assuming you wanted to align the "right" column, with "total cost" also.

Answer (score 0):

you won't be able to do that with the for[each] you are using, but if you use the traditional for, you could get one item from the first list and use the index to get it from the second list.

Anyway, the best approach would be to have a class that could handle both the name of the item and its value, then, you would need only to iterate over a single list.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do it for you.

```
for(int i=0;i<l.size();i++) {
  System.out.print("1 x " +l.get(i) );
  System.out.print(" total cost ");
  System.out.println("£"+c.get(i));
}
```

Comment: (p.s. using an object would be the best way to do this, providing you've already learnt them)

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i=0;i<c.size();i++) {
// print the value using l.get(i) & c.get(i)
}
```

BTW what you need to use in such a case is Java.Util.Map implementation as you want to co-relate the key (Commodity name) and value (price of the commodity and number of items , Commodity Object)